# Unable to connect Apache Spark running in docker

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to connect a Spark Cluster running within the docker via the host system. I tried both the python script and `spark-shell` both gave the same results:

**Within Docker**

```
park-master_1  | 20/07/24 10:13:26 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
spark-master_1  | java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1574364215946805297, local class serialVersionUID = 6543101073799644159
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
spark-master_1  |   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
spark-master_1  |   at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
spark-master_1  |   at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:108)
spark-master_1  |   at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Nett
```

Running `spark-shell` on the command line from the host system gives the following error:

➜

```
  docker-spark-cluster git:(master) ✗ spark-shell --master spark://localhost:7077 
20/07/24 15:13:17 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
20/07/24 15:14:25 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
20/07/24 15:14:25 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
20/07/24 15:14:25 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
20/07/24 15:14:26 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2555)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(SparkSession.scala:930)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
```

**Docker Containers**

```
git:(master) ✗ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
dfe3d47790ee        spydernaz/spark-worker:latest   "/bin/bash /start-wo…"   42 hours ago        Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:32769->8081/tcp                                    docker-spark-cluster_spark-worker_2
c5e36b94efdd        spydernaz/spark-worker:latest   "/bin/bash /start-wo…"   42 hours ago        Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:32768->8081/tcp                                    docker-spark-cluster_spark-worker_3
60f3d29e9059        spydernaz/spark-worker:latest   "/bin/bash /start-wo…"   42 hours ago        Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:32770->8081/tcp                                    docker-spark-cluster_spark-worker_1
d11c67d462fb        spydernaz/spark-master:latest   "/bin/bash /start-ma…"   42 hours ago        Up 23 minutes       6066/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7077->7077/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->8080/tcp   docker-spark-cluster_spark-master_1
➜  docker-spark-cluster git:(master) ✗
```

**Spark Shell Commands**

`spark-shell --master spark://localhost:7077`

Comment: What's the version of spark running in docker and spark you using locally?

Comment: @koiralo under docker pySpark says it's 2.4.3 and host it is 3.0.0. I did change Spark Version. I am using this cluster setup `https://github.com/mvillarrealb/docker-spark-cluster.git`

Comment: Did you try using the same version in both?

Comment: @koiralo Yes I fixed it across containers and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @koiralo already mentioned in the comments, this is due to the version difference in pySpark running in local and on the server.

Had the same error and it was fixed once the versions at both the places were matched.